# Seaborn plot does not show all column values

Tags: python, plot, bar-chart, seaborn, color-palette

I have the following dataframe:

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Year': ['2017','2018','2019','2019','2019','2019','2020','2020'],
      'Threshold':[96, 91, 20.59, 47.37, 78.12, 10.00, 15.00 ,91],
      'Fee' : ["No","No", "20%", "20%", "5%", "20%", "20%", "No"]})
```

I am using seaborn to plot it:

```
palette={"No": "g","20%": "y", "5%": "r"}

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(10,8)

sns.barplot(x="Year", y="Threshold",hue = 'Fee', palette = palette, data=my_df, ci=None)

for p in ax.patches: 
    ax.annotate("%.2f" % p.get_height(), (p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2, p.get_height()),
                ha='center', va='center', fontsize=11, color='black', xytext=(0, 10), 
                textcoords='offset points',fontweight='bold')
```

However, the displayed graph returns the average of the Threshold variable per Year and I want to show all 8 dataframe Thresholds on the graph.

[Seaborn plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxHSO.png)

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Year': ['2017','2018','2019','2019','2019','2019','2020','2020'],
      'Threshold':[96, 91, 20.59, 47.37, 78.12, 10.00, 15.00 ,91],
      'Fee' : ["No","No", "20%", "20%", "5%", "20%", "20%", "No"]})

palette={"No": "g","20%": "y", "5%": "r"}

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(10,8)

g = sns.barplot(x=my_df.index, y="Threshold",hue = 'Fee', palette = palette, data=my_df, ci=None)
g.set(xticklabels=my_df['Year'])

for p in ax.patches: 
    ax.annotate("%.2f" % p.get_height(), (p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2, p.get_height()),
                ha='center', va='center', fontsize=11, color='black', xytext=(0, 10), 
                textcoords='offset points',fontweight='bold')
```

[image: New Graph]

Comment: This is what I wanted to plot.  Changing the x axis made the difference. Thanks Ventkatesh Prabhu.

Comment: Just an additional question. Is there a way to put the bars for the same year together? I mean the 4 bars for the year 2019 together and the 2 bars for the year 2020 together too.